# Link complements in $\mathbb{R}^{3} $ and $S^{3} $

Tags: knot-theory

What's the difference between a link complement in $S^{3} $ and a link complement in $R^{3} $? Are they homeomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

They're clearly not homeomorphic as one is compact and the other is not. The main similarity though is that two $\mathbb{R}^3$ knot complements (not link complements) are homeomorphic iff the corresponding knots are isotopic (up to chiral pairings) iff the same knot complements in the one-point compactification (the corresponding link complements in $S^3$) are homeomorphic. So they are as strong as each other as far as being a knot invariant is concerned.

It is also not hard to see that the fundamental groups of both types of link complements will be isomorphic (Van Kampen's theorem). This is called the knot/link group.

Comment: The bit about compactness probably does not say what you meant.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Possibly. I'm prone to making mistakes. Is the complement in the $3$-sphere of an open tubular neighbourhood of a link not a compact manifold with boundary homeomorphic to a disjoint union of tori, and is the complement in Euclidean $3$-space of an open tubular neighbourhood of a link not an unbounded, and hence non-compact space? Hence no pair (one from each class of spaces) can be homeomorphic.